# Netflix catalogue by country

Tags: api, netflix

Since Netflix API has closed, where can I find an up-to-date catalogue by country ?

The Netflix Roulette API http://netflixroulette.net/api/ would be perfect if it provided information about the country in which every movie/series is available on Netflix.

Comment: Did you got anything related to this... I am also looking for Netflix API where I can get list of movies/Series and its related information. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Same over here :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ended up here looking for the same thing. I'm a bit late to the party but, for future readers, there now are now a few APIs providing up-to-date country-based catalogs, and not just for Netflix.

See the [Movie of the Night
Streaming Availability API](https://www.movieofthenight.com/about/api) and the [JustWatch Streaming API](https://www.justwatch.com/us/JustWatch-Streaming-API).